# How do I add a user settings check when sending notifications?

Tags: django-channels

I use [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create notifications. I want to add user settings check:

```
def send_notification(title, body, sender, recipient):
    if not recipient.settings.in_app_notification:
        return

    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    return async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        f'{recipient.user.id}',
        dict(
            type='create_notification',
            title=title,
            body=body,
            sender=str(sender.user.id),
            recipient=str(recipient.user.id),
        )
    )
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```